# What is the reaction mechanism of a 5-endo-trig cyclization?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am trying to solve this mechanism for a disfavoured 5-endo-trig cyclisation to generate the disfavoured product (4) from starting material (1). The favoured 5-exo-trig is given by (2), which I have got a mechanism for. My efforts take me to intermediate (3) as shown below, but I'm not too sure on how to generate the desired product without reagent reduction.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mechanism to the 5-endo-trig product (4) is very close.  Notice however that when you do the initial cyclization, the intermediate formed has a **positive charge on nitrogen** along with the negative charge on oxygen (as you showed).  This cyclized intermediate then just needs to move a proton from the nitrogen to oxygen to form the neutral enol which then converts to the (ester) carbonyl - which is your desired product.  No other reagents are required.

[image]

Comment: Additionally, the OP's second step is not possible, the pi bond cannot move into the ring since the destination carbon already have four bonds